# How do i implement dynamic checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-forms

I am trying to implement dynamic forms for my angular application and i am following the https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

I have a checkbox question with more than 4 checkbox options.

My checkbox question model as of now is similar to dropdown with only one formControllerName ("fruits_key")

```
export class CheckBoxQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = "checkbox";
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options["options"] || [];
 }
```

and my object is

```
new CheckBoxQuestion({
            key: "fruits_key",
            label: "Choose Fruits",
            options: [
              { key: "Apple", value: true },
              { key: "Orange", value: false },
              { key: "Grapes", value: false },
              { key: "Banana", value: false }
            ]
          })
```

Here is my html to display the checkbox items

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let opt of question['options']; index as idx">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [formControlName]="question.key"
            [checked]="opt.value" ">
          <label class="custom-control-label">{{opt.key}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Q) The issue is with [formControlName] which is set to the same for all the checkbox items.  How do i correctly implement the check box items, Do i need to rewrite the checkbox model? Please advise if you have a better solution.

Angular Site Demo: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div *ngFor="let option of question['options']; let i=index" [formArrayName]="question.key" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" id="{{question.key +'_'+ option.key}}" class="custom-control-input" (change)="getUpdate(question)"/>
            <label for="{{question.key +'_'+ option.key}}" class="custom-control-label">{{option.key}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
 </ng-container>
```

and my question control service which converts the model to Form Groups/Form Controls/Form Arrays.

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionControlService {
constructor() {}

toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[]) {
let group: any = {};

questions.forEach(question => {
  if (question.controlType === "checkbox") {
    group[question.key] = this.buildCheckBoxArray(question["options"]);
  } else {
    group[question.key] = question.required
      ? new FormControl(question.value || "", Validators.required)
      : new FormControl(question.value || "");
  }
});
return new FormGroup(group);
}

buildCheckBoxArray(itemsArr): any {
 const arr = itemsArr.map(item => {
   return new FormControl(item.value);
 });
 return new FormArray(arr);
}
}
```